# Error on SimpleTemplateEngine embedded in Java: Could not instantiate custom Metaclass for class: java.util.ArrayList

Tags: groovy, groovyshell

I have a app where my users input a HTML template with SimpleTemplateEngine notation, and execute this template with code above, in a Java Class:

```
new SimpleTemplateEngine().createTemplate(templateStr).make(map).toString()
```

and I obtain this error:

```
groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Could not instantiate custom Metaclass for class: java.util.ArrayList. Reason: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: groovy.runtime.metaclass.java.util.ArrayListMetaClass.<init>(groovy.lang.MetaClass)
```

I observe that error occurrs in a loop in a java.util.ArrayLIst in a JPA Entity loaded by Hibernate:

```
<%for(int k=0; k< Registro[i].listUsers.size();k++){%>

HTML CODE

<%}%>
```

Anyone can help me? I no have more ideas about this error...
Thanks!

Comment: The part Registro[i] actually loses me. What are you trying to achieve doing that? I'm quite sure the issue is around that.

Comment: Maybe you should include relevant Registro class code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that the part `Registro[i]` is for getting the value of a static property which name is held under the variable `i` (or at least that is what will happen) unless the `getAt(String)` method has been overloaded on `Registro`.

Either way I also guess that returns an object that has a `listUsers` property that should be at least a `Collection`.

Maybe the problem is with the initialization of said `listUsers` property.

Some `Registro` code could be used for better understanding.

Comment: The list is initialized like a ArrayList. I don't believe that is the problem.

Comment: The problem ocurrs when I use a java.lang.String or a java.util.List not instantiate like a LinkedList.